# Is there a quicker way than a binary search to find a record with certain attributes in a sorted Kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a client that will subscribe to a Kafka topic, in which the starting offset is determined at subscription time. The topic is sorted on a timestamp value in the Value object of the record. The client can specify a timestamp to start consuming from, and I currently use a binary search using the seek() and poll() methods of the Kafka Consumer to find the correct offset. This seems hack-y to me, and I'm wondering, is there a more appropriate way to be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Kafka version you're using, there is an API to actually get that from the KafkaConsumer https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#offsetsForTimes-java.util.Map-

```
public java.util.Map<TopicPartition,OffsetAndTimestamp> offsetsForTimes​
      ( java.util.Map<TopicPartition,java.lang.Long> timestampsToSearch,
        java.time.Duration timeout)
```

You can simply pass in the different `TopicPartition`s, as well as the timestamp as a  `Long`, and it will return the offsets you need.

When I used this, I then did a `seek` call to the offset returned minus one, just to make sure I was still getting all the data I needed.  Of course, you have to be able to tolerate duplicates for this.

**Updated:**
The OP mentioned that the timestamp value only exists inside the record itself.  So maybe try setting the timestamp value explicitly when producing the message into Kafka?  When you're creating the `ProducerRecord` to send, set the timestamp explicitly to the value of the timestamp in the record itself.  And then try the above solution.

I haven't tried it, it might not work, especially if the incoming records have timestamps that are all over the place, but maybe it's an option.

Another thing I would caution is that Kafka doesn't guarantee ordering with multiple partitions, so even though the messages will be *roughly* in correct order, there's no guarantee.  If you really want iy, Kafka *will* guarantee ordering of messages, but only with a *single partition* topic.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for me. The timestamp in reference in that method is the timestamp at which the topic received a particular record. The timestamp I'm referring to is a timestamp contained within the record itself which has no relation to the timestamp that record was received. I'm more looking for a solution which can seek to a record by some attribute contained within that record.

Comment: @Owen edited the original answer with some other ideas.  Maybe that helps.